# Is there another way to connect JS to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a collapsible directory list in HTML/CSS/JS, but it seems like it doesn't work (the collapsible part). Everything else is totally fine. Can you help me, please?

The code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="directory-list">
    <li>assets
        <ul>
            <li>css
                <ul>
                    <li>typography.css</li>
                    <li>layout.css</li>
                    <li>modules.css</li>
                    <li>states.css</li>
                    <li>theme.css</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const allFolders = $(".directory-list li > ul");
    allFolders.each(function() {

        const folderAndName = $(this).parent();
        folderAndName.addClass("folder");

        const backupOfThisFolder = $(this);
        $(this).remove();
        folderAndName.wrapInner("<a href='#' />");
        folderAndName.append(backupOfThisFolder);

        folderAndName.find("a").click(function(e) {
            $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle("slow");
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is trying to use jQuery... does your page include the jQuery library? if not, you will need to add it to use those methods. e.g. if you add `<script      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>` I'd expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to jquery. Your own javascript seems to be referencing it.

you can add this link in your header tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or you can make the collapsible function with vanilla (plain) javascript:

https://codepen.io/sheelah/pen/EPEOBb

Or even CSS:

https://alligator.io/css/collapsible/

Comment: ... I would personally take the jquery ref link approach. No need to recreate the wheel.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It helped!